# Dynamic view names in ui router states in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `ui-view`,

```
    <div ui-view="filtersView_ModalA" class="filter-container"></div>
```

Now, I want to make generic routes, so that going forward, if any new filterView needs to be implemented like say,

```
    <div ui-view="filtersView_ModalB" class="filter-container"></div>
```

My `route` can handle the same.

**I am getting ModalA or ModalB from** `stateParams.prodType`.

```
    .state('Modal.tabs', {
        url: .......,
        views: {

            'filtersView_{{stateParams.prodType}}@Modal.tabs': {
                templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
                // stateParams.prodType works here
                .....

            },
```

It's not working.

I also tried , `'filtersView_' + stateParams.prodType + '@Modal.tabs' : {`

Nothing worked.

Or, `can I declare a constant and concat the values in view names?`

**Am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't compose the view-name.

But you can do that using named views in different states. You can specify which component should be rendered in the view in which state. See more in the documentation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

And also this entry: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still could not figure out how to leverage the same in my UI. Could you help me with an example ?

Comment: Edit your question and describe your view structure